# how to target nested element in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nested

i am trying to target and get the text in element with class b ,how do I get it

```
   <span class="a ">
            <span class="b "><!-- some random number --></span> 
            posts
        </span>
```

I have tried this but this throws an error ,I want to make it clear

> I dont want to target the element using class

and

> I want to target it using xpath

```
post = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text,"posts")]').text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

post = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(.,"posts")]/span'))).text
```

Comment: until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @NikhilSingh check weather your element located inside iframe

Comment: actually no ,Ill tell you what I am trying ,I am actually making a instagram bot that will check the number of posts of any account

Comment: try targeting a random account like this

Comment: @NikhilSingh provided piece of HTML seem to be incorrect. this should work `//a[contains(.,"posts")]/span`

Comment: thanks actually I solved the problem ..the problem was reffering to the xpath when i was  logged in ,and the bot was working without logging in ,..so it turns out that the structure was different in both the cases